# IRR in poi return NaN but correct value in excel

Tags: excel-formula, apache-poi, irr

When i calculate Irr value use apache/poi i get Double.NaN, but the same inputs in excel i got a negative value.

So why they return different value?

```
inputs here:

irr(-1.0601017230994111E8,19150.63,44505.08,22997.34,33936.39,27265.92,2127.66,2108.63,886.53,2482.27,4305.12,3421.58,65644.12,1020.51,2659.57,3191.49,20284508.4,1881279.27,11675415.09,7557862.28,921090.46,622104.32,289267.36,183.41,886.53, 0.1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it gives the #NUM! error in current `apache poi 4.1.0`, not `NaN`.

The problem is about your given guess. In [IRR-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IRR-function-64925EAA-9988-495B-B290-3AD0C163C1BC) it is stated:

> **Guess**   Optional. A number that you guess is close to the result of IRR.
>
> Microsoft Excel uses an iterative technique for calculating IRR. Starting with guess, IRR cycles through the calculation until the
>   result is accurate within 0.00001 percent. If IRR can't find a result
>   that works after 20 tries, the #NUM! error value is returned.
>
> In most cases you do not need to provide guess for the IRR calculation. If guess is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.1 (10
>   percent).
>
> If IRR gives the #NUM! error value, or if the result is not close to what you expected, try again with a different value for guess.

The result of your `IRR` would be -0.050193141 in `Excel`. But your guess is 0.1. So using that guess the internal `apache poi` `IRR` function does not find a result which is accurate within 0.00001 percent after 20 tries. So the #NUM! error value is returned.

Why `apache poi`'s `IRR` function is not the same as in `Excel`? Well because that part of `Excel` is not open source. So nobody really knows how it works.

Using a **guess** of -0.1 works for me.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class ExcelEvaluateIRR {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Double[] values = new Double[] {
    -1.0601017230994111E8,
    19150.63,
    44505.08,
    22997.34,
    33936.39,
    27265.92,
    2127.66,
    2108.63,
    886.53,
    2482.27,
    4305.12,
    3421.58,
    65644.12,
    1020.51,
    2659.57,
    3191.49,
    20284508.4,
    1881279.27,
    11675415.09,
    7557862.28,
    921090.46,
    622104.32,
    289267.36,
    183.41,
    886.53
   };

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row = null;
   Cell cell = null;
   for (int r = 0; r < values.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(values[r]);
   }
   row = sheet.createRow(values.length);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   //cell.setCellFormula("IRR(A1:A" + values.length + ",0.1)"); // will not work
   cell.setCellFormula("IRR(A1:A" + values.length + ",-0.1)"); // will work
   FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
   CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);
   System.out.println(cellValue);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```