# How to save excel with formula in Apache Poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

If there is a cell with a formula and save the file, then after manually closing the file, the excel will be asked to Save the changes? How to make a full save of file from the program because without this saving, I cannot get the correct value by reading the file.

Current file saving:

```
        File file = new File("Test.xlsx");
        FileOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            workbook.write(out);
            workbook.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Formula update:

```
        XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
        workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

Formula:

```
XSSFCell irrCell = row1.createCell(0);
irrCell.setCellFormula("IFERROR(IRR(A2:C2),0)");
```

File reading:

```
        try {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Cell values: -20000000, -1000, 2399000

Programm formula cell value: 0, file formula cell value: -0,653687014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the cases where `Microsoft` does not follow their own rules. [IRR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/irr-function-64925eaa-9988-495b-b290-3ad0c163c1bc?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) tells:

> Microsoft Excel uses an iterative technique for calculating IRR.
> Starting with guess, IRR cycles through the calculation until the
> result is accurate within 0.00001 percent. If IRR can't find a result
> that works after 20 tries, the #NUM! error value is returned.
>
> In most cases you do not need to provide guess for the IRR
> calculation. If guess is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.1 (10
> percent).

This is exactly what `apache poi` has implemented for `IRR` function. And that's why it gets the `#NUM!` error for your data sample. But `Microsoft` seems to do something different.

Using the formula `IRR(A2:C2,-0.7)`, which has a given guess of `-0.7`, also `apache poi` is able to evaluate that `IRR` formula.

To get around this, one could do what `IRR` function description also tells:

> If IRR gives the #NUM! error value, or if the result is not close to
> what you expected, try again with a different value for guess.

So try a `guess` from -1.0 to 1.0 in steps of 0.1 until you get a value instead of the `#NUM!'  error.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

class ExcelEvaluateIRRFunction {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx")); String filePath = "./ExcelNew.xlsx";
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = sheet.getRow(1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(1);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(-20000000d);
  row.createCell(1).setCellValue(-1000d);
  row.createCell(2).setCellValue(2399000d);

  row = sheet.getRow(0); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

  CellValue evaluatedValue = null;
  for (int i = -10; i < 10; i++) {
   double guess = i/10d;
   System.out.println(guess);
   cell.setCellFormula("IRR(A2:C2," + guess + ")");
   evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
   evaluatedValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
   System.out.println(evaluatedValue);
   if (evaluatedValue.getCellType() != CellType.ERROR) break;
  }

  evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
  System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close() ;
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

See also [IRR in poi return NaN but correct value in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336072/irr-in-poi-return-nan-but-correct-value-in-excel/58336783#58336783) for another example of the same problem.